# how to make my url look like this www.example.com/userid in yii2 and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

I have www.example.com/school/index?id=value and i want to change it to www.example.com/value to display the school page, how do i write my htaccess to permit it

This is my .htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine on

  # hide files and folders
  RedirectMatch 404 /_protected
  RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
  RedirectMatch 404 /composer\.
  RedirectMatch 404 /.bowerrc


  # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
  RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: why `.htaccess` you should be consuming the `UrlManager` and set all your seo friendly urls there. read about it [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)

Comment: sorry am new in yii, how will i create a rule so that when i call www.example.com/schoolusername which will display the school page, i want to make this address to be the default username for school so that whenever they want to visit thier page they will just type the name of the website/username

Answer (score 0):

In the config file:

```
[
    'components' => [
        # code ...
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<id:\d+>'  => 'school/index',
            ],
        ],
        # code ...
     ],
]
```

**Details:**

 If the **id**(value) contains `letters` and `"_"`, you should use the following:(Regular expressions)

```
'<id:\w+>'  => 'school/index',
```

**ID** Above = Action Parameter Name

```
public function actionIndex($id)
{
   // ...
}
```

**Update -details:**

You should adjust the regular expressions section according to the type of your id value.(According to your need)

For example: If your **ID** is **Integral** Only (ID value):

```
'<id:\d+>'  => 'school/index',
```

**example2**: `letters, _ , -`

`'<id:[\w\-]+>'  => 'school/index',`

**or**

```
'<id:[A-Za-z0-9_-]+>' => 'school/index',
```

for `letters, _ , -, ., @`   **:**  `'/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.@]+$/'`

Phrase,_ , -, .`:`'/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+( [-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)*$/'`

---

### Regular expressions

> "**\w**" A word character is a character from **a-z, A-Z, 0-9**, including the
>   **_ (underscore)** character

```
   Metacharacter    Description          
   ------------     ---------------    
   \d               Match any digit
   \D               Match any non-digit
   \w               Match any word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
   \W               Match any non-word character
   \s               Match any white space character (\r,\n,\t,\f)
   \S               Match any non-white space characte
   ^                Beginning of a string.
   $                End of a string.(The end of a line)
   +                Match one or more of the previous
   ?                Match zero or one of the previous
   *                Match zero, one or more of the previous
   .                Wildcard character, matches any character
```

also `{ }`   Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous

{m,n} Match previous RE m to n times greedily. **Example**:

`/\d{3}/` // matches 3 digits ("312", "122", "12312321" but not "12")

`/\d{3,7}/` // matches digits that occur between 3 and 7 times

Comment: so you mean by add '<id:\w+>'  => 'school/index', to my rules if i call www.example.com/schoolname it will display the school page

Comment: Thank you i have add this to my url rule and it work bu please i dont get this  '<id:[\w\-]>'  => 'school/index', or [A-Za-z0-9_-]+

Comment: I apologize. Edited. The correct expression: `'<id:[\w\-]+>'`